# Angular no ejecuta el servicio tipado para invocar una api

Tags: angular, webapi, angular9

estoy realizando un aplicación en Angular 9 que se conecta a una API.NET; he realizado pruebas con otros métodos y funcionan correctamente,pero sucede algo bastante extraño cuando mi componente llama un método del servicio `buscaClienteB(): string` o al indicar 'buscaClienteB(): miclase'. No alcanza a ejecutarlo y no manda ningún error.
El html del componente: el evento que interesa es keyup de mi input text verificacliente()

```
    <div class="card-container listado">
    <ul>
        <li class="lst" *ngFor="let plan of planes" >{{plan.nombre}}</li>
    </ul>
    Periodo de: <input type="text" value="60" (keyup)="mandaDias(dias.value)" #dias /> dias &nbsp;&nbsp;Su id Cliente:<input type="text" value="1" (keyup)="verificacliente(txtid.value)" #txtid />
    <input type="button" (click)="mandaDias(dias.value)" [routerLink]="['/contratos']" name="btnAdquirir" disabled value="Tu vida está en riesgo" #asegurabtn> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" enabled value="Cancelar"  (click)="resetActivo(asegurabtn)" #cancelabtn>
</div>
```

El typescript de componente:

```
   constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,public listaplanes:ServicePlanesService,public apiseguro:WcfserviceService) {
    this.planes = [
      { nombre: "PLAN A", id: 1 },
      { nombre: "PLAN B", id: 2 },
      { nombre: "PALN C", id: 3 },
     .........
      { nombre: "PLAN L", id: 9 }
    ]
  }
verificacliente(_id){
  //this.listaplanes.buscaclient(_id);
  this.apiseguro.buscaClienteB;//<- Esta es la invocación que me interesa
  console.log('se llamó api buscaClienteB');//<- Esto siempre escribe en consola
}
```

El codigo del servicioAngular:

```
 buscaClienteB(): string {//<-     
    let observ = this._http.get(`${this.url3}?id=7`);
    //return this._http.get<cliente>(`${this.url3}?id=${_idcliente}`);//Este metodo lo invocaba antes desde otro servicio pero el resultado q devolvía undefined
    console.log('urlpeticion:'+this.url3);
    let oCliente: cliente;
    observ.subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
      oCliente.Apellidos = resp.toString();
    })
    
    console.log('oCliente.Apellidos:'+oCliente.Apellidos);
    console.log(' --wcfservice; metodoB terminado');
    return oCliente.Apellidos;
  }
```

Adjunto link en video para detalles: http://srecorder.com/s/9phq
no recibo error en consola.
Pensé que quintando la segunda referencia del servicio volvería a funcionar
http://srecorder.com/s/9phu pero al parecer ya no ejecuta directo del servicio angular ni usando el servio el mismo angular que llama a mi otro servicio

Answer (score 0):

buscaClienteB es una funcion pero no la estas llamando:

```
verificacliente(_id){
  //this.listaplanes.buscaclient(_id);
  this.apiseguro.buscaClienteB;//<- Esta es la invocación que me interesa
  console.log('se llamó api buscaClienteB');//<- Esto siempre escribe en consola
}
```

deberías tener:

```
verificacliente(_id){
  //this.listaplanes.buscaclient(_id);
  this.apiseguro.buscaClienteB();//<- Esta es la invocación que me interesa
  console.log('se llamó api buscaClienteB');//<- Esto siempre escribe en consola
}
```

considerando que tu problema es la parte asíncrona yo te propongo la siguiente solución en la que el buscaClienteB retorne el observable y luego te suscribas a el

```
buscaClienteB(): any {//<-     
    return this._http.get(`${this.url3}?id=7`);
  }
```

y por el lado de verificacliente

```
verificacliente(_id){
  this.apiseguro.buscaClienteB().subscribe(
    resp => {
      console.log(resp);
      // aquí tu ves que hacer con la respuesta
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: pegaste exactamente lo mismo

Comment: agregue unos parentesis al final de buscaClienteB ->  this.apiseguro.buscaClienteB();

Comment: vale gracias, lo cierto es que el comportamiento que tiene es que no espera la respuesta de la api y manda el error en consola y un segundo depués me obtiene el resultado

Comment: Tal vez por usar servicio intermedio, como que pierde el hilo de respuesta y lo toma como respuesta incorrecta, obté por llamar directamente al servicio que conecta la api verificar el tipado de datos.quedó solucionado

Comment: eso es porque todas las  http request son asíncronas, usualmente cuando programas con request http tienes que hacerlo con un modelo basado en promesas o explicitamente decirle a la request que no sea asíncrona

Comment: en tu variable observ, la función que esta dentro del subscribe funciona en otro hilo por lo que puede terminar antes o después que la función buscaClienteB

Comment: Gracias @LPZadkiel, solo una ultima ayuda, tienes un link o me podrías decir cómo indico a mi solicitud que sea síncrona?

Comment: tienes que usar `async - await`. Este link te puede servir https://medium.com/@pavankjadda/synchronous-http-calls-in-angular-7-using-async-and-await-d0af7910f6d7

Comment: gracias @LPZadkiel, aunque tu ultimo comentario, creo no me entendiste; el async await ya sé que es asíncrono, pero yo buscaba síncrono o secuencial.Al final esto ya lo comenté en otro  tema.